# Is there an analytical description of the NACA 642-015A profile?

Tags: aerodynamics, wind-tunnel, nasa

While searching for symmetric profiles I stumbled across different definitions (point-clouds) of the NACA 642-015A profile.

1. http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/seligdatfile?airfoil=n64015a-il
2. http://www.airfoildb.com/airfoils/418.dat

The figure below (skewed) shows the difference in percent chord on the secondary axis (green markers).

[image]

What causes these differences and is there a analytical description I could use to create a point-cloud with higher resolution.

Another question is:
The NACA Reports I could find via Google all feature the NACA 642-015 (without the "A"). The difference between NACA 642-015**A** and NACA 642-015 is an increased thickness of the **A**-version towards the trailing edge.
Who introduced or developed the **A**-version?

Comment: Have you tried [Theory Of Wing Sections](https://www.scribd.com/book/271527757/Theory-of-Wing-Sections-Including-a-Summary-of-Airfoil-Data) by Abbott & Von Doenhoff?

Comment: sure, but I could not find the 64_2 015A in them, do you have a profile description in yours?

Comment: The "A" simply denotes that the last 20% of the contour are straight lines. This was made to simplify the construction of wing and flaps.

Answer (score 1):

[This report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19930092747.pdf) seems to include a reference to an analytical description of 6-series airfoils

[image]

On your second question: found this reference in Synthesis Of Subsonic Airplane Design by E. Torenbeek:

> A modification to the standard series is the A-series in which the sharp trailing edge angle is replaced by a larger one, resulting from straight contours which run from 80% chord backwards.

The paragraph contains a reference to "Theoretical and experimental data for a number of NACA 64-series airfoil sections" which turns out to be [NACA LM R6J01](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20050092351.pdf)

Comment: Thanks @Koyovis, this helped a lot, really!. BUT (I'll open a new question for this though, I am not able to use the equations to create the airfoils. I'll get there, thanks!

Comment: Actually I just realised that the equation you cited does not recreate the thickness-distribution but the chamber-line, which is a straight line for a symmetrical airfoil.